# Unknown error in android studio while installing the debug apk

Tags: java, android, firebase, handler

I'm a beginner in Android studio, and I beg pardon for and writing errors. While trying an ecommerce app to install, I'm getting this error, however I tried searching web for the same, yet could not find it. Can you please help me what this error is about? Earlier this project used Session manager to authenticate, I tried to use Firebase when I faced this issue. Please post any related link.
10/01 13:04:25: Launching 'app' on Micromax Micromax Q391.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

> List of apks: [0]
> 'D:\SearchLocally\SerchLocally\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 9779378'
> returns error 'Unknown failure: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No
> implementation found for java.lang.String
> android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(java.lang.String) (tried
> Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get and
> Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get__Ljava_lang_String_2) at
> android.os.SystemProperties.native_get(Native Method) at
> android.os.SystemProperties.get(SystemProperties.java:52) at
> android.os.Environment.getCanonicalPathOrNull(Environment.java:832) at
> android.os.Environment.(Environment.java:78) at
> android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:419)
> at android.os.Debug.(Debug.java:96) at
> android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:164) at
> android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:91) at
> org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug at
> android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:176) at
> android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:93) at
> org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug at
> android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:187)
> at
> android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
> at
> org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)''
> Retry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disabling MIUI optimization from developed options will work:
Settings - Developer options - MIUI optimization
Disable it and it will ask to reboot the device, after that the app can be installed